# Shring text even when using text-overflow: nowrap

Tags: html, css, reactjs, styles

I am cutting of my extra text using the following code:

```css
div {
  &>h1 {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
    white-space: nowrap !important;
  }
  background: red;
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Long text that will be cutt Off</h1>
</div>
```

Now even though the extra text becomes cut off by poviding ...after the text, and when I try to shrink the elements the text doesn't get reduced or the text is not responsive after cutting off. Does anybody know how can I achieve both of the issues:

1. Cut off the extra text when the text is too long inside the div
2. The text should responsive when shrinking or reducing the browser window

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it can help you

```css
h1 {
    width: 200px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    margin: 0;
    background: white;
    resize: horizontal;
}
body {
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Long text that will be cutt Off</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the max-width after your h1 customization, so it won't work well

Try this one

```
div {
  background: red;
  max-width: 100px;
}

div > h1 {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Or this one

```
div {
  background: red;
  max-width: 100px;

  & > h1 {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis !important;
    white-space: nowrap !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: but it's not shrinking the text when browser gets narrower

Comment: then you have to set it inside responsive media query

Answer (score 0):

```
h1 {
    text-overflow: inherit;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
h1 {
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
}
```

Or you can do this using some useState hook, you can manually slice the text and if the useState doesnt meet the length of the text it will return ...